# Convert Formatted String Output with empty cells to PS Object

Tags: powershell, split

I have string output from a command I'm trying to turn into an object-oriented PSObject.  The output looks like this:

```
NAME                         STATUS    VOLUME                      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS       AGE    VOLUMEMODE
app1-iscsi-pvc0              Bound     app1-iscsi-pv0              100Gi      RWO                               236d   Filesystem
app1-iscsi-pvc1              Bound     app1-iscsi-pv1              5Gi        RWO                               236d   Filesystem
app1-iscsi-pvc2              Bound     app1-iscsi-pv2              5Gi        RWO                               236d   Filesystem
mssql-iscsi-pvc              Bound     mssql-iscsi-pv0             100Gi      RWO            manual             310d   Filesystem
my-claim                     Bound     my-local-pv                 2Gi        RWO            my-local-storage   242d   Filesystem
app1.2-pvc-app1.2-0          Bound     app1.2-pv0                  50Gi       RWO            manual             309d   Filesystem
app1.2-pvc-app1.2-1          Bound     app1.2-pv1                  50Gi       RWO            manual             309d   Filesystem
app1.2-pvc-app1.2-2          Bound     app1.2-pv2                  50Gi       RWO            manual             309d   Filesystem
app1.1-pvc-app1.1-0          Bound     app1.1-pv0                  100Gi      RWO            manual             308d   Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xx-pvc0           Bound     app3-iscsi-xx-pv0           5Gi        RWO            manual             77d    Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xxxx-pvc0         Bound     app3-iscsi-xxxx-pv0         5Gi        RWO            manual             91d    Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xxxx-pvc0         Bound     app3-iscsi-xxxx-pv0         5Gi        RWO            manual             109d   Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xxxx-pvc0         Bound     app3-iscsi-xxxx-pv0         5Gi        RWO            manual             91d    Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xxx-pvc0          Bound     app3-iscsi-xxx-pv0          5Gi        RWO            manual             97d    Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xxxxx-pvc0        Bound     app3-iscsi-xxxxx-pv0        5Gi        RWO            manual             91d    Filesystem
app3-iscsi-pvc0              Bound     app3-iscsi-pv0              50Gi       RWO                               186d   Filesystem
app3-iscsi2-pvc0             Bound     app3-iscsi2-pv0             5Gi        RWO            manual             110d   Filesystem
```

...the problem I'm having is the empty 'cells' in the storage class column.  All other output formats correctly with the current method I'm using except this output because of the empty cells.    Using my existing method, where there are empty cells, the following data ends up in the preceding column because my split is working off of collapsing the blank space.

Here is the code I'm presently using:

```
$p = Invoke-Expression 'kubectl get pvc -o wide'
$o = @()

## Determine header column.  The '\s{2,}' is to match everything with > 2 spaces in succession
$h = ($p[0] -replace '\s{2,}', '|||||') -split '|||||',0,"simplematch"
for ($i = 1; $i -lt $p.Count; $i++) {
    $e = ($p[$i] -replace '\s{2,}', '|||||') -split '|||||',0,"simplematch"
    
    $t = New-Object pscustomobject

    ## Add each member from the two different arrays into the psobject
    for ($x=0; $x -lt $h.Count; $x++) {
        $t | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $h[$x].Replace(' ', '_') -Value $e[$x]
    }
    
    $o += $t  
}

$o | ft
```

...is anyone aware of a strategy to address converting the variably spaced output, sometimes with empty cells, into a psobject reliably?  TIA!

Comment: You might want to download and try [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable)

Comment: @iRon That did work -- nice script.  If you want to add it as an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: @iRon, Also, it threw an exception using the file (ConvertFrom-SourceTable.ps1 $p) but after I dot-sourced it (. ConvertFrom-SourceTable.ps1 $p), I could directly use the function just fine:  ConvertFrom-SourceTable $p -- without error.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have changed it to a function file. Meaning that you can now (from version `0.4.0`) directly invoke it after a `Load-Script ConvertFrom-SourceTable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) cmdlet:

```
$Table = '
NAME                         STATUS    VOLUME                      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS       AGE    VOLUMEMODE
app1-iscsi-pvc0              Bound     app1-iscsi-pv0              100Gi      RWO                               236d   Filesystem
app1-iscsi-pvc1              Bound     app1-iscsi-pv1              5Gi        RWO                               236d   Filesystem
app1-iscsi-pvc2              Bound     app1-iscsi-pv2              5Gi        RWO                               236d   Filesystem
mssql-iscsi-pvc              Bound     mssql-iscsi-pv0             100Gi      RWO            manual             310d   Filesystem
my-claim                     Bound     my-local-pv                 2Gi        RWO            my-local-storage   242d   Filesystem
app1.2-pvc-app1.2-0          Bound     app1.2-pv0                  50Gi       RWO            manual             309d   Filesystem
app1.2-pvc-app1.2-1          Bound     app1.2-pv1                  50Gi       RWO            manual             309d   Filesystem
app1.2-pvc-app1.2-2          Bound     app1.2-pv2                  50Gi       RWO            manual             309d   Filesystem
app1.1-pvc-app1.1-0          Bound     app1.1-pv0                  100Gi      RWO            manual             308d   Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xx-pvc0           Bound     app3-iscsi-xx-pv0           5Gi        RWO            manual             77d    Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xxxx-pvc0         Bound     app3-iscsi-xxxx-pv0         5Gi        RWO            manual             91d    Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xxxx-pvc0         Bound     app3-iscsi-xxxx-pv0         5Gi        RWO            manual             109d   Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xxxx-pvc0         Bound     app3-iscsi-xxxx-pv0         5Gi        RWO            manual             91d    Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xxx-pvc0          Bound     app3-iscsi-xxx-pv0          5Gi        RWO            manual             97d    Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xxxxx-pvc0        Bound     app3-iscsi-xxxxx-pv0        5Gi        RWO            manual             91d    Filesystem
app3-iscsi-pvc0              Bound     app3-iscsi-pv0              50Gi       RWO                               186d   Filesystem
app3-iscsi2-pvc0             Bound     app3-iscsi2-pv0             5Gi        RWO            manual             110d   Filesystem'

Load-Script ConvertFrom-SourceTable # If needed, accept the repository warning
$Data = ConvertFrom-SourceTable $Table
$Data |Format-Table

NAME                  STATUS VOLUME               CAPACITY ACCESS MODES STORAGECLASS     AGE  VOLUMEMODE
----                  ------ ------               -------- ------------ ------------     ---  ----------
app1-iscsi-pvc0       Bound  app1-iscsi-pv0       100Gi    RWO                           236d Filesystem
app1-iscsi-pvc1       Bound  app1-iscsi-pv1       5Gi      RWO                           236d Filesystem
app1-iscsi-pvc2       Bound  app1-iscsi-pv2       5Gi      RWO                           236d Filesystem
mssql-iscsi-pvc       Bound  mssql-iscsi-pv0      100Gi    RWO          manual           310d Filesystem
my-claim              Bound  my-local-pv          2Gi      RWO          my-local-storage 242d Filesystem
app1.2-pvc-app1.2-0   Bound  app1.2-pv0           50Gi     RWO          manual           309d Filesystem
app1.2-pvc-app1.2-1   Bound  app1.2-pv1           50Gi     RWO          manual           309d Filesystem
app1.2-pvc-app1.2-2   Bound  app1.2-pv2           50Gi     RWO          manual           309d Filesystem
app1.1-pvc-app1.1-0   Bound  app1.1-pv0           100Gi    RWO          manual           308d Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xx-pvc0    Bound  app3-iscsi-xx-pv0    5Gi      RWO          manual           77d  Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xxxx-pvc0  Bound  app3-iscsi-xxxx-pv0  5Gi      RWO          manual           91d  Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xxxx-pvc0  Bound  app3-iscsi-xxxx-pv0  5Gi      RWO          manual           109d Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xxxx-pvc0  Bound  app3-iscsi-xxxx-pv0  5Gi      RWO          manual           91d  Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xxx-pvc0   Bound  app3-iscsi-xxx-pv0   5Gi      RWO          manual           97d  Filesystem
app3-iscsi-xxxxx-pvc0 Bound  app3-iscsi-xxxxx-pv0 5Gi      RWO          manual           91d  Filesystem
app3-iscsi-pvc0       Bound  app3-iscsi-pv0       50Gi     RWO                           186d Filesystem
app3-iscsi2-pvc0      Bound  app3-iscsi2-pv0      5Gi      RWO          manual           110d Filesystem
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but if the column widths are reliable, you could just do the work up front to cut out the fields.

```
$String =
@(
'NAME                         STATUS    VOLUME                      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS       AGE    VOLUMEMODE'
'app1-iscsi-pvc0              Bound     app1-iscsi-pv0              100Gi      RWO                               236d   Filesystem'
'app1-iscsi-pvc1              Bound     app1-iscsi-pv1              5Gi        RWO                               236d   Filesystem'
'app1-iscsi-pvc2              Bound     app1-iscsi-pv2              5Gi        RWO                               236d   Filesystem'
'mssql-iscsi-pvc              Bound     mssql-iscsi-pv0             100Gi      RWO            manual             310d   Filesystem'
'my-claim                     Bound     my-local-pv                 2Gi        RWO            my-local-storage   242d   Filesystem'
'app1.2-pvc-app1.2-0          Bound     app1.2-pv0                  50Gi       RWO            manual             309d   Filesystem'
'app1.2-pvc-app1.2-1          Bound     app1.2-pv1                  50Gi       RWO            manual             309d   Filesystem'
'app1.2-pvc-app1.2-2          Bound     app1.2-pv2                  50Gi       RWO            manual             309d   Filesystem'
'app1.1-pvc-app1.1-0          Bound     app1.1-pv0                  100Gi      RWO            manual             308d   Filesystem'
'app3-iscsi-xx-pvc0           Bound     app3-iscsi-xx-pv0           5Gi        RWO            manual             77d    Filesystem'
'app3-iscsi-xxxx-pvc0         Bound     app3-iscsi-xxxx-pv0         5Gi        RWO            manual             91d    Filesystem'
'app3-iscsi-xxxx-pvc0         Bound     app3-iscsi-xxxx-pv0         5Gi        RWO            manual             109d   Filesystem'
'app3-iscsi-xxxx-pvc0         Bound     app3-iscsi-xxxx-pv0         5Gi        RWO            manual             91d    Filesystem'
'app3-iscsi-xxx-pvc0          Bound     app3-iscsi-xxx-pv0          5Gi        RWO            manual             97d    Filesystem'
'app3-iscsi-xxxxx-pvc0        Bound     app3-iscsi-xxxxx-pv0        5Gi        RWO            manual             91d    Filesystem'
'app3-iscsi-pvc0              Bound     app3-iscsi-pv0              50Gi       RWO                               186d   Filesystem'
'app3-iscsi2-pvc0             Bound     app3-iscsi2-pv0             5Gi        RWO            manual             110d   Filesystem'
)

$Objects = 
$String | 
Select-Object -Skip 1 |
ForEach-Object{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        NAME         = $_.SubString(0, 28 ).Trim()
        STATUS       = $_.SubString(29, 9 ).Trim()
        VOLUME       = $_.SubString(39, 27).Trim()
        CAPACITY     = $_.SubString(67, 10).Trim()
        ACCESSMODES  = $_.SubString(78, 14).Trim()
        STORAGECLASS = $_.SubString(93, 18).Trim()
        AGE          = $_.SubString(112, 6).Trim()
        VOLUMEMODE   = $_.SubString(119   ).Trim()
    }
}

$Objects | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Does the job, clean, fast, and readable.

Comment: Thanks Steven but this is dynamic for a lot of different output -- I was trying to shy away from hard-coding anything.  This is variable length data which means it's variably spaced data.